# Configure RasPi 4 for headless operation

Tags: headless, raspi-config, sudo, wpa-supplicant

I'm trying to run a Pi 4 headless as I don't have the microusb cord available.

In `/boot`, I ran `touch ssh` then created `wpa_supplicant.conf` and with the modified contents:

```
country=US
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
ssid="<My Network's ID>"
scan_ssid=1
psk="<Password key for the network>"
key_mgmt="WPA-PSK"
}
```

I've tried this on ***both*** a ***new*** sd card that came with RasberryPi OS but (based on some advice that the sd card was corrupted) also on a ***fresh install on another sd card***. Neither worked.

The ***specific problem*** I'm having is that, on saving, I'm getting an error, `E212: Can't open file for writing: read-only file system`. With that in mind in tried the following:

1. `:w !sudo tee % > /dev/null` from this answer [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8253362/etc-apt-sources-list-e212-cant-open-file-for-writing#8253435%5D)
2. Delete the .conf file, touching a new one and then trying to with sudo vim wpa_supplicant.conf.
3. Sudoers list. Apparently the Pi doesn't have one.

At this point, I don't know what the error is. I've tried both Pi and Raspberry for the passwords.

Any suggestion?

Comment: *The specific problem I'm having is that, on saving, I'm getting an error* - saving what? the wpa_supplicant file? what are you using (Windows PC? Linux PC? Mac?) to create that file?

Comment: Note: if you are using raspberry pi imager, you can use `ctrl-shift-x` to bring up extended options to set up things like SSH, wifi access and more

Comment: One. step at a time:Did the `touch ssh` actually create a file in the `/boot` directory of the sd card which you are going to boot the pi from?

Comment: It's still not clear. How can you get an error message from a headless Pi with no SSH access?

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear from your Question exactly what you are doing, or if you actually have a problem.

The normal (and recommended) approach is to put the `wpa_supplicant.conf` in the boot directory and reboot.

Answer (score 0):

The raspberry pi imager has the hidden menu accessed by control-x which allows setting of host name, wifi parameters ssh password etc.

It saves having to edit the files manually.